# How can i get specific file size by using node_exporter?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

How can I get file size for the specific file.

For example, I need the file size of /var/lib/mysql/abcd

/var/lib/mysql is the mount point. So I can get the file size of this directory. But how can i achive the **/var/lib/mysql/abcd** file size?

```
node_filesystem_size_bytes{mountpoint="/var/lib/mysql"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by creating cron task writing size of required file in metrics format into file, and then [enabling node_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#textfile-collector) to serve that file.

Try to use something along the lines of following:

1. Create `custom_metrics.sh` with following content:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo '# HELP node_file_size_bytes Size of specified folder in kilobytes'
echo '# TYPE node_file_size_bytes gauge'
echo 'node_file_size_bytes {path="/var/lib/mysql/abc"} '$(du -s /var/lib/mysql/abc 2>/dev/null | cut -f1)
```

2. Create folder where file with custom metrics will be stored

```bash
mkdir -p /var/lib/node_exporter
```

3. Add task of updating file with metrics to cron

```
* * * * * full/path/to/script/from/step/1/custom_metrics.sh >/var/lib/node_exporter/custom_metrics.prom.new && mv /var/lib/node_exporter/custom_metrics.prom.new /var/lib/node_exporter/custom_metrics.prom
```

4. Edit `/edit/default/node_exporter`, and add `--collector.textfile.directory=/var/lib/node_exporter` to the list of options. If the options are currently empty then it will look like this:

```
OPTIONS='--collector.textfile.directory=/var/lib/node_exporter'
```

5. Restart `node_exporter`

```bash
systemctl restart node_exporter
```